# Jquery UI autocomplete w/Infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to load more data on scroll in my autocomplete textbox
When the user scrolls downward it will function like
pagination loading more results as needed.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lp6zP/).

I've been searching for quite a while and I'm having
a problem finding similar problem like mine.

```
       <div class="ui-widget">
              <label for="tags">Enter Company Name: </label>
              <input id="tags" class="form-control">
            </div>

    <script> 
 $( function() {
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'function/all_company_auto.php'
        });
      } );
</script>
```

Here is my php code.

```
<?php
$get_company = "SELECT DISTINCT companies.company
        FROM companies
        INNER JOIN target_details
        ON companies.company_id = target_details.company_id
        WHERE companies.company LIKE \"%$company%\"
        LIMIT 100 OFFSET 10
        ";
        if($run_company = $conn->query($get_company)){
            while($row = $run_company->fetch_assoc()){
                $data[] = $row['company'];
            }
             echo json_encode($data);
        }
?>
```

Comment: Seems hard to justify hitting the server so often... Can't you just send all of the possible values one time?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart could you explain it?

Comment: I'm making a lot of assumptions but, rather than have your autocomplete box request more values from the server every time the user scrolls down x times, why not just send all of the possible values in one single request? This avoids hitting the server for no reason. There is a good amount of overhead for an HTTP request and if you can avoid it, you should.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart I tried it loading all the results at one go.The servers response was so slow. So I decided to use limit and its working with optimal response time.So I was wondering If I could apply pagination as "load more" function.

Comment: I see. Is it possible something else is slowing it down? There would need to be a *lot* (and I mean a *lot*) of values to slow down the response noticeably.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart I could only guess its the amount of data I'm loading.Because after the LIMIT clause was used.Response is very optimal.

Comment: Ok, try this then [Ajax Autocomplete](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139793/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-matthew-goulart).

Comment: Sorry I cant, the chat is blocked at work.

Comment: I read the link you gave me,Its kinda same as the one I'm using.No pagination documentation though.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit, I meant it more as a starting point for you to "hack". I don't know of any projects that implement the specific functionality you are looking for. I think the reason is because, as I said, what you are trying to do is likely to hit the server very often.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart I see.Thank your for the information tho.Appreciate it.

Comment: First you will have to setup your PHP to be told which results to display. Then your jQuery will have to keep asking for results. So there is a lot to do, but your paginating your results basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, your PHP will need to be able to collect a conditional amount of results.

This might look like this:

```
<?php
$start = isset($_POST['o']) ? int($_POST['o']) : 0;  // Offset
$count = isset($_POST['l']) ? int($_POST['l']) : 100; // Limit
$company = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['term']); // Search Term, protected from SQL Injection

$get_company = "SELECT DISTINCT companies.company
  FROM companies
  INNER JOIN target_details
  ON companies.company_id = target_details.company_id
  WHERE companies.company LIKE \"%$company%\"
  LIMIT $count OFFSET $start";
if($run_company = $conn->query($get_company)){
    while($row = $run_company->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row['company'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

So now when we request more data, we can send `{ o: 10, l: 100, term: "app" }` for example. Pulling from the example you gave, it might look a bit like this:

```
_scrollMenu: function(ul, items) {
  var self = this;
  var startShow = 10;
  var maxShow = 100;
  var results = [];
  var pages = Math.ceil(items.length / maxShow);
  $.ajax({
    url: "function/all_company_auto.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      o: startShow,
      l: maxShow,
      term: self.request.term
    },
    dataType: "json",
    sucess: function(data);
    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
      results.push(v);
    });
  });
  //results = items.slice(startShow, maxShow);

  if (pages > 1) {
    $(ul).scroll(function() {
      if (isScrollbarBottom($(ul))) {
        ++window.pageIndex;
        if (window.pageIndex >= pages) return;

        results = items.slice(window.pageIndex * maxShow, window.pageIndex * maxShow + maxShow);

        //append item to ul
        $.each(results, function(index, item) {
          self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
        //refresh menu
        self.menu.deactivate();
        self.menu.refresh();
        // size and position menu
        ul.show();
        self._resizeMenu();
        ul.position($.extend({
          of: self.element
        }, self.options.position));
        if (self.options.autoFocus) {
          self.menu.next(new $.Event("mouseover"));
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $.each(results, function(index, item) {
    self._renderItem(ul, item);
  });
}
```

The problem with this example is that the amount of items is known. You would have to do a preliminary query to collect the total possible results. So this will start to fall apart. Also this is not the best use of autocomplete.

If you could clarify why you want to get so many results instead of limiting it, it would better.